# Delete tag: [awesonium]

Tags: discussion, tags

I believe the [awesonium](/questions/tagged/awesonium) tag was added in error.  It appears to be a typo for the valid [awesomium](/questions/tagged/awesomium) tag.

There are no questions tagged with [awesonium](/questions/tagged/awesonium).

Comment: Er. (a) All three tags you mention are, actually, the same tag, so I don't know what you think is a typo for what. (b) Unused tags are automatically deleted by the system, though it can take a day or so.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen  Correction, awesomium is the valid tag.

Comment: You might want to correct the spelling in your comment - you had it right in your post.

Comment: As @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen says, tags are automatically deleted after 24 hours when there are no questions in them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tag [awesonium](/questions/tagged/awesonium) was created [about 18 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20393799/revisions). More preceisly at **2013-12-05 08:23:22Z**

As [Trig points out in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210334/delete-tag-awesonium/210336#comment674536_210334), tags are automatically deleted by the system after 24 hours of inactivity. Therefore, since this tag was removed about 9 hours ago, it should be gone in less than 15 hours of writing this.